# Check which array has the highest length inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Im using lodash.js but seems like there isnt a way to do this.
I tried myself but im not happy with the result

```js
function checkHighestArrayCountFromObject(object) {
  var counter = 0;
  for (let property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      counter = object[property].length > counter ? object[property].length : counter
    }
  }
  return counter
}


var obj = {
  a: [2, 3, 4, 5],
  b: [2, 3, 4],
  c: [2, 3],
  d: [2],
}

console.log(checkHighestArrayCountFromObject(obj)) // => length of (a) should be returned
```

What im not seeing.

Comment: What's the problem? It returns `4`, which is correct.

Comment: "`im not happy with the result`"...which part are you not happy with?

Comment: You can use `_.maxBy` from Lodash for this.

Comment: @lealceldeiro i just wanted the shortest way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Lodash you can use `_.max`:

```
_.max(Object.values(obj).map(a => a.length))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the values from the object using `Object.values`,
map them to their length,
and finally use `reduce` to find the maximum value:

```
Object.values(obj).map(a => a.length).reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another compact way to write this is to use `Math.max`:

```
function checkHighestArrayCountFromObject(object) {
  return Math.max(...Object.values(object).map(o => o.length))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {
  a : [2,3,4,5],
  b : [2,3,4,],
  c : [2,3],
  d : [2],
}

_.chain(obj)
.reduce((max,v,k)=> {
  if(v.length>max.len){
    max.len = v.length;
    max.key=k
  };
  return max
},{len:-1,key:''})
.get('key').value()
```

Or Simply do a reduce on the obj and get the property key from the result

Answer (score 0):

If using lodash you can use reduce

```
_.reduce(obj, (max, n) => n.length > max ? n.length : max, 0);
```